# substr() foreign characters gives me black diamonds with white questions marks

Tags: php, html, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm taking foreign (Japanese) characters from a database and using substr() to limit the length of the string.

However when I do this it cuts off a character from the string and that leaves behind one of those question marks in black diamonds as a replacement character (�)

Everything (Documents, Charset, table encoding) are set to UTF-8.

Here is an example of what happens

```
$string = "日本最大級のポータルサイト。"
echo substr($string, 0,10);
```

Which outputs 日本最�

How do you reccomend I find/replace this question mark icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/substr) when dealing with UTF-strigs since each symbol there will be represented as multiple bytes, not single byte (for non-ASCII characters). And [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/substr) works with *bytes*. Instead you should use [`mb_substr()`](https://www.php.net/mb_substr) which will safely and correct return desired result.

To work with multibyte strings in PHP there is [`mbstring`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) extension, and `mb_substr()` is part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mb_substr() so long as it is enabled on your server.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php